# How do you save a reference to another document in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to save a document to the database, which contains a reference to another document.

However, when I POST the document, Mongoose replaces the `_id` I send it, with something else.

Here's my Mongoose code (in Express)

```
var resultItem = new models.Round_Results({
        selection: result.selection,
        time: result.time,
        round: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result.round)
    });
    models.User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user){
        user.results.push(resultItem);
        user.save(function(err, result){
            ...
        });
    });
```

Here's the Schema:

```
schemas.round_results = new mongoose.Schema({
    round: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Round'},
    selection: Number,
    time: Number
});
var Round_Results = mongoose.model("Round_Results", schemas.round_results);
```

And here's the code I'm sending to the server, for example:

```
var results = {
    round: 555ec731385b4d604356d8e5,
    selection: 10,
    time: 19
};
```

But in the database, it appears with a different `round` ID. For example, it comes out like

```
{ selection: 10,
  time: 19,
  round: 5573ef74536a1e58489e59c4,
  _id: 5573ef74536a1e58489e59c5 }
```

Why is this happening?

What is the proper to save a reference to another document, when building a web app with Mongoose?

Comment: Umm! Another document? Do you mean more than one? Because your current schema is defined to only have a singular reference.

Comment: I want to save a `Round_Result` which has a reference to another document - that document being `Round`

Answer (score 1):

mongoose added a _id field for sub document.

to cancel it, add id false for your schema:

```
schemas.round_results = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id:false,
    round: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Round'},
    selection: Number,
    time: Number
});
var Round_Results = mongoose.model("Round_Results", schemas.round_results);
```